# How to acces a file that you put in with your web app client?

Tags: javascript, html, file-access

Let's say I make a web app. This web app wants to access a txt file that is in the same directory as the web app. I would want to be able to access this txt file from javascript.

However this is client side javascript and not Nodejs. How can I do this?
USE CASE: Imagine that you have a long list of items that rarely updates as txt file and you want to present some of the items to the user in your client. I don't want to create an api just for this.

I want to be able to transform the txt file that is already there to a javascript list or some other javascript data structure which I can then use in my javascript client.

**Ok it seems that you can access this txt file on the web server by using the url/nameofthefile.txt. So I think that I should make a get request from my javascript code to get access to the content of the txt file. I'm not sure if this is the way to go.**

Comment: If I'm getting this right, what you mean is you want to **read** a locally present text file in nodejs? Also, this will stay purely client side?

Comment: I don't want to use node js. When you deploy the client side you only have html css and js with this txt file as well. Now how do I access this txt file in javascript considering that there is no nodejs and it's all client side javascript?

Comment: This seems possible if you can somehow create anf put that file on a small server (even at client side). JS technically **can** access local `files:///` using XHR but most modern browsers prevent it from running because of CORS violation.

Comment: Imagine I used something like netlify. I would drag and drop the folder containing the project which contains index.html and other html files, javascript files, css files and the txt file I want to use. So how do I access that txt file with js? Is this a CORS violation?

Comment: It essentially just like uploading an image for your profile, except in this case there are multiple files, obviously. Things like these are handled at server side and you definitely need a server for that.